# Tapestry + JDO + GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, tapestry

I tried to run Tapestry on GAE. After some time, I was able to resolve the last errors to display at least a simple page. But, to be honest, some sort of data-storage would be nice.
I tried to use tapestry-jdo, but there is my Problem: Im unable to use any part of JDO, and I have tried for days.

I will post my pom.xml, on which I have worked. I tried a lot of combinations for the version numbers, but mostly the actionlink to test JDO fails, because org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory is not found.
 The rest of the time, I got an uncaught exception from tapestry, caused by another missing JDO class, but this time not while the construction of the JDOEntityManagerSource, instead somewhere deeper.

I havent learned programming, I teached it to myself, so my maven knowledge is limited.
This pom.xml may contain needles entries.

If i build it with maven, i get `Could not transfer metadata asm:asm/maven-metadata.xml from/to local.repository (file:../../local.repository/trunk): No connector available to access repository local.repository` under some circumstandes.

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Example</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Example</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdo2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3-eb</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-RC3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
            <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tynamo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-jdo</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Provided by the servlet container, but sometimes referenced in the application code. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>Example</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <serverId>appengine.google.com</serverId>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--
                        This plug-in "enhances" your domain model objects (i.e.
                        makes them persistent for datanucleus)
                    -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.4</version>

                <configuration>
                    <mappingIncludes>**/entities/*.class</mappingIncludes><!--*/ just to stop formatig the rest of the code as comment-->
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <enhancerName>ASM</enhancerName>
                    <api>JDO</api>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                                <artifactId>transaction-api</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
                        <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>datanucleus-enhancer</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>tapestry-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>codehaus.snapshots</id>
            <url>http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>maven-gae-plugin-repo</id>
            <name>Maven Google App Engine Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>data-nucleus</id>
            <url>http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>tapestry-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>maven-gae-plugin-repo</id>
            <name>maven-gae-plugin repository</name>
            <url>http://maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository</url>
        </pluginRepository>

    </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>
        <tapestry-release-version>5.3.2</tapestry-release-version>
        <gae.version>1.6.3</gae.version>
        <datanucleus.version>1.1.5</datanucleus.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datanucleus-appengine plugin v2 ought to be used with DataNucleus jars v3.0.* and with javax.jdo jdo-api v3.0.1 ... as per the docs for GAE at
http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/UpgradingToVersionTwo

Comment: I guess thats the solution, ill try it soon. Your link says i should use org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory, but the official documentation still contains org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory